# Laravel Environments in Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to have different domains for my application based on the environment;

Like so; `www.prod.co.uk` and `www.dev.co.uk`
Now in my `route.php` I have defined subdomains like so;

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'www.prod.co.uk']
Route::group(['domain' => 'blog.prod.co.uk']
Route::group(['domain' => 'careers.prod.co.uk']
```

In the `laravel` documentation you can access the `env` based on what your have in your `.env` can I do something like below in my `route.php`?

```
Use App;

if (App::environment('production')) {
    // The environment is local
    $domain = www.prod.co.uk;
    $subdomain1 = blog.prod.co.uk;
    $subdomain2 = careers.prod.co.uk;
}

if (App::environment('local', 'staging')) {
    // The environment is either local OR staging...
    $domain = www.dev.co.uk;
    $subdomain1 = blog.dev.co.uk;
    $subdomain2 = careers.dev.co.uk;
}


Route::group(['domain' => $domain]
Route::group(['domain' => $subdomain1]
Route::group(['domain' => $subdomain2]
```

Comment: `Use App;` will give you a syntax error, and is unnecessary in the `routes.php` file. But yes, this basic idea is doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nicer (IMHO) way to do this would be to define your custom domains in .env files – this way it's clear that domain names are environment-specific and there won't be a need for any 'ifs':

.env:

```
URL=www.dev.co.uk 
SUBDOMAIN1=blog.dev.co.uk
SUBDOMAIN2=careers.dev.co.uk
```

Then add to config/app.php:

```
'url' => env('URL'),
'subdomain1' => env('SUBDOMAIN1'),
'subdomain2' => env('SUBDOMAIN2'),
```

routes.php would become simpler and nicer to read:

```
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.url')] {}
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.subdomain1')] {}
Route::group(['domain' => Config::get('app.subdomain2')] {}
```

PS. Imagine if you get more environment-specific URLs in the future – your routes.php will get bloated and it will (it already does, actually) contain environment-specific data which is not nice!

Comment: Cheers, Don't think I need to use `config...` We can access them like this; `env('URL')`

Comment: I think it's not recommended. It's mentioned somewhere in 5.2 documentation, as far as I remember it's related to configs being cached. Also, it's more agnostic this way – what if in the future you decide to keep configurations in the database instead of .env files? Using env() makes you stuck to environment files.

Comment: I tried your method and I got an error about not finding the `route`

Comment: Actually my bad... I didn't add your code to `config/app.php`

Comment: Can I access `Config::get...` in `session.php`?

Comment: You shouldn't even try! :)) config/session.php is something that SETS the config, it shouldn't rely on itself. But feel free to use env() in session.php!